# How to use defer or webworker api with SquishIt MVC framework?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, squishit

I am using SquishIt MVC framework for bundling and minification of the js and css components present in the application. The code is as mentioned below:

```
public static class HTMLHelperExtensions
{
  public static MvcHtmlString PackageLibs(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
  {
    var client = Bundle.JavaScript() 
     .Add("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
     .Add("~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js")
     .Render("~/scripts/combined.js");

    return new MvcHtmlString(client);
  }
}
```

I am invoking the method : HTMLHelperExtensions from the layout page.

```
<%= HTMLHelperExtensions() %>
```

I want to use the defer attribute to boost the JavaScript performance of a web page.

Can anyone help me to know the usage of the defer attribute? I would like to know also is the usage of webworker useful here.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render with deferred load, change your bundle setup like so:

```
 var client = Bundle.JavaScript() 
     .Add("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
     .Add("~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js")
     .WithDeferredLoad()
     .Render("~/scripts/combined.js");
```

Web workers seem like overkill for something as trivial as script loading IMO.